# Angularjs radio button and checkbox value save & get

Tags: angularjs, checkbox, radio-button

I am creating Q & A page for user response with three different type of answers

- Text
- Checkbox
- Radio button

Question is configured in database with answer type & options. 
Text question answer can easily saved & updated in database **but getting error for Radio & Checkbox type**.

```
<div ng-repeat="questions in QuestionAndAnswer">
<div>
    {{$index + 1}}. &nbsp;{{questions.QuestionText}}
</div>
<br />
<div ng-repeat="selectedAns in questions.selectedAnswers" ng-if="questions.QuestionType==='Text'">
    <input type="text" name="ans_{{questions.QuestionId}}" ng-model="selectedAns.Answer" class="form-control" />
</div> 
<div ng-repeat="ansoption in questions.AnswerOptions">
    <div id="oneChoiceAns" ng-if="questions.QuestionType==='Onechoice'">
        <input type="radio" name="radAns" ng-model="ansoption.AnswerOptionId" value="{{ansoption.IsSelected}}" id="{{ansoption.AnswerOptionId}}">
        {{ansoption.AnswerOptionText}}
    </div>
    <div id="multiChoiceAns" ng-if="questions.QuestionType==='Multichoice'">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="ansoption.IsSelected" ng-value="ansoption.IsSelected" />
        {{ansoption.AnswerOptionText}}
    </div>
</div>
```

[Sample output screen of which answer needs to save in DB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A4oee.png) 
For checkbox selected option I am entering multiple selected answer option/choice rows in answer table where as for Radio only selected option should be added.

While retrieving from database both checkbox & radio should be selected.
Following table structure I am using for same code

Config table where Question saved

**QuestionTable**
QuestionId  int
QuestionType    varchar(50)
QuestionText    varchar(MAX)

Config table where Question's multiple available answer options saved

**AnswerOptions**
AnswerOptionId  int 
QuestionId  int 
AnswerOptionText varchar(MAX)

Table where user response stored
**QAResponse**
QuestionId  int 
AnswerOptionId  int 
Answer  varchar(MAX)

Comment: with provided code and description, your problem is not clear. Please consider adding a JS Fiddle link or a code snippet.

Comment: I am kind of missing the question in this. What exactly do you need help with?

Comment: I want to save the selected radio/checkbox value to database and retrieve same in edit mode

Comment: what is the data type for radio and checkbox values in db

Comment: There will be no value for radio/checkbox in database. Table AnswerOptions holds option text associated with each option & QAResponse will be the table which hold selected AnswerOptionId against QuestionId. If User answers the text question in that case AnswerOptionId is null and Answer field will be the answer text holder.